# explicit and implicit model specification in randomForest leads to different results

Tags: r, input, model, random-forest

I am using a simple data set extracted from Cars93 in the MASS package in R.  I am running a randomForest on this simple data set predicting origin (usa or non-usa) from four other predictors.  If i reference the origin variable by it's explicit location in the data set as shown below (it's in the fifth column of tempdata) i get totally different answers than when I reference by name.  It is a factor and I am using the same random seeds to start.  Can anyone shed light on this.  If i look at tempdata$origin==tempdata[,5] i get a vector of size 93 (93 data points with all TRUEs) so it's the exact same data here as the outcome.  Thank you in advance for your help.

```
set.seed(2000)
> testF<-randomForest(tempdata3[,5]~., data=tempdata3[,1:5], ntree=100, 
                      na.action=na.omit, seed=2014)
> testF$votes[1:10,]
           USA    non-USA
2    0.1315789 0.86842105
6    0.9487179 0.05128205
8    1.0000000 0.00000000
8.1  1.0000000 0.00000000
10   1.0000000 0.00000000
12   0.9729730 0.02702703
12.1 0.9756098 0.02439024
13   0.9512195 0.04878049
13.1 0.9705882 0.02941176
13.2 0.9259259 0.07407407

set.seed(2000)
> testF<-randomForest(Origin~., data=tempdata3[,1:5], ntree=100, 
                      na.action=na.omit, seed=2014)
> testF$votes[1:10,]
           USA   non-USA
2    0.7027027 0.2972973
6    0.6571429 0.3428571
8    1.0000000 0.0000000
8.1  1.0000000 0.0000000
10   1.0000000 0.0000000
12   0.8947368 0.1052632
12.1 0.8918919 0.1081081
13   0.3636364 0.6363636
13.1 0.5128205 0.4871795
13.2 0.4571429 0.5428571

tempdata3 is here:

tempdata3
        Type MPG.highway Passengers Length  Origin id
2    Midsize          25          5    195 non-USA  2
6    Midsize          31          6    189     USA  6
8      Large          25          6    216     USA  8
8.1    Large          25          6    216     USA  8
10     Large          25          6    206     USA 10
12   Compact          36          5    182     USA 12
12.1 Compact          36          5    182     USA 12
13   Compact          34          5    184     USA 13
13.1 Compact          34          5    184     USA 13
13.2 Compact          34          5    184     USA 13
16       Van          23          7    178     USA 16
16.1     Van          23          7    178     USA 16
16.2     Van          23          7    178     USA 16
17       Van          20          8    194     USA 17
18     Large          26          6    214     USA 18
20     Large          28          6    203     USA 20
21   Compact          28          6    183     USA 21
21.1 Compact          28          6    183     USA 21
22     Large          26          6    203     USA 22
22.1   Large          26          6    203     USA 22
22.2   Large          26          6    203     USA 22
22.3   Large          26          6    203     USA 22
23     Small          33          5    174     USA 23
23.1   Small          33          5    174     USA 23
28    Sporty          24          4    180     USA 28
29     Small          33          5    174     USA 29
30     Large          28          6    202     USA 30
30.1   Large          28          6    202     USA 30
31     Small          33          4    141     USA 31
33   Compact          27          5    177     USA 33
33.1 Compact          27          5    177     USA 33
34    Sporty          29          4    180     USA 34
35    Sporty          30          4    179     USA 35
36       Van          20          7    176     USA 36
37   Midsize          30          5    192     USA 37
38     Large          26          6    212     USA 38
39     Small          50          4    151 non-USA 39
40    Sporty          36          4    164 non-USA 40
41    Sporty          31          4    175 non-USA 41
42     Small          46          4    173 non-USA 42
42.1   Small          46          4    173 non-USA 42
43   Compact          31          4    185 non-USA 43
43.1 Compact          31          4    185 non-USA 43
44     Small          33          5    168 non-USA 44
44.1   Small          33          5    168 non-USA 44
44.2   Small          33          5    168 non-USA 44
47   Midsize          27          5    184 non-USA 47
47.1 Midsize          27          5    184 non-USA 47
47.2 Midsize          27          5    184 non-USA 47
48   Midsize          22          5    200 non-USA 48
49   Midsize          24          5    188 non-USA 49
49.1 Midsize          24          5    188 non-USA 49
50   Midsize          23          4    191 non-USA 50
50.1 Midsize          23          4    191 non-USA 50
51   Midsize          26          6    205     USA 51
51.1 Midsize          26          6    205     USA 51
53     Small          37          4    164 non-USA 53
55   Compact          34          5    184 non-USA 55
55.1 Compact          34          5    184 non-USA 55
57    Sporty          25          2    169 non-USA 57
57.1  Sporty          25          2    169 non-USA 57
58   Compact          29          5    175 non-USA 58
60    Sporty          26          4    166     USA 60
63   Midsize          24          5    190 non-USA 63
66       Van          23          7    190 non-USA 66
66.1     Van          23          7    190 non-USA 66
66.2     Van          23          7    190 non-USA 66
66.3     Van          23          7    190 non-USA 66
68   Compact          31          5    188     USA 68
69   Midsize          31          5    190     USA 69
70       Van          23          7    194     USA 70
71     Large          28          6    201     USA 71
72    Sporty          30          4    173     USA 72
74   Compact          31          5    181     USA 74
74.1 Compact          31          5    181     USA 74
76   Midsize          27          5    195     USA 76
77     Large          28          6    177     USA 77
79     Small          38          5    176     USA 79
80     Small          37          4    146 non-USA 80
81     Small          30          5    175 non-USA 81
82   Compact          30          5    179 non-USA 82
84     Small          37          5    162 non-USA 84
85    Sporty          32          4    174 non-USA 85
86   Midsize          29          5    188 non-USA 86
86.1 Midsize          29          5    188 non-USA 86
88     Small          33          4    163 non-USA 88
89       Van          21          7    187 non-USA 89
91    Sporty          25          4    159 non-USA 91
91.1  Sporty          25          4    159 non-USA 91
92   Compact          28          5    190 non-USA 92
93   Midsize          28          5    184 non-USA 93
93.1 Midsize          28          5    184 non-USA 93
```

Comment: It's because the first way is wrong. Formulas should only contain _names_ of variables, and (relatively) simple transformations (e.g. `log(var)`). In your first example, `Origin` is included as a covariate, I'm pretty sure.